# Is there a way to have multiple programs without having multiple projects?

Tags: codeblocks

I'm using Codeblocks and don't want to create a new project every time i want to code something different. Is there any way to have something like a single project and then just open the files to work on them?

In other words for example: I have one CPP file with some arrays and another file to read and write data from a text file. What I'm currently doing is having another separated project for the second file I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single project (with a single call of the main function) you can have, for example, a menu that calls several functions that execute the different pieces of code that interest you.
You can only have one `int main()` function call.